# Next js: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have used Next Js for my project, I have ready backed logic to show my data, but when I try show my all data by `useEffect` hook and display with `map` function then show me error like this:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

[image]

I don't know where is problem, I have tried by this way:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Linkj from "next/link";
import Router from "next/router";
import { isAuth, getCookie } from "../../actions/auth";
import { create, getCagetories, removeCategory } from "../../actions/category";

const Category = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    name: "",
    error: false,
    success: false,
    categories: [],
    removed: false,
  });
  const { name, error, success, categories, removed } = values;
  const token = getCookie("token");

  useEffect(() => {
    loadCategories();
  }, []);

  const loadCategories = () => {
    getCagetories().then((err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        setValues({ ...values, categories: data });
      }
    });
  };

  const shwoCategories = () => {
    return categories.map((c, i) => {
      return (
        <button key={i} className="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1 mt-3">
          {c.name}
        </button>
      );
    });
  };

  const clickSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    create({ name }, token).then((data) => {
      if (data.error) {
        setValues({ ...values, error: data.error, success: false });
      } else {
        setValues({ ...values, error: false, success: true, name: "" });
      }
    });
  };
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValues({
      ...values,
      name: e.target.value,
      error: false,
      success: false,
      removed: "",
    });
  };
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <form onSubmit={clickSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label className="text-muted">Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={name}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
            Create
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
      {shwoCategories()}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Category;
```

Any Suggestion Please.

Comment: Well, it's saying that 'categories' is undefined. Maybe try values.categories.map, see if that works better.

Comment: I have already store data inside `categories` in `loadCategories ` function

Comment: try `categories?.map` It will prevent the error and I think categories is undefined.

Comment: Thank you I solved my problem, actually `categories` was undefined, that was problem in my `getCategories` function which is API can't load data from backend.

Answer (score -1):

Update your code like this. the problem is you have to use 'values.categories' not 'categories' for get categories list.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Linkj from "next/link";
import Router from "next/router";
import { isAuth, getCookie } from "../../actions/auth";
import { create, getCagetories, removeCategory } from "../../actions/category";

const Category = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    name: "",
    error: false,
    success: false,
    categories: [],
    removed: false,
  });
  const { name, error, success, categories, removed } = values;
  const token = getCookie("token");

  useEffect(() => {
    loadCategories();
  }, []);

  const loadCategories = () => {
    getCagetories().then((err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        setValues({ ...values, categories: data });
      }
    });
  };
  // Update this function
  const shwoCategories = () => {
    return values.categories.length ? values.categories.map((c, i) => {
      return (
        <button key={i} className="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1 mt-3">
          {c.name}
        </button>
      );
    }) : null;
  };
  // update end

  const clickSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    create({ name }, token).then((data) => {
      if (data.error) {
        setValues({ ...values, error: data.error, success: false });
      } else {
        setValues({ ...values, error: false, success: true, name: "" });
      }
    });
  };
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValues({
      ...values,
      name: e.target.value,
      error: false,
      success: false,
      removed: "",
    });
  };
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <form onSubmit={clickSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label className="text-muted">Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={name}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
            Create
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
      {shwoCategories()}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Category;
```

Comment: He destructured `categories`, so it is the same as `values.categories`.

Comment: Your logic is true! but I didn't get data from `values`, I have destructured data from `categories` which is sore data in my database.